# Problem regarding upgrading ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, partial-upgrade

After I started the upgradation, The steps like downloading the new packages, installing the new packages went well without any error. After that step, My software update app got freezed and it remained freezed for like 2 hours almost. Then I force restarted my system with restart button. But after restart, it was Ubuntu 18.04. So I'm not sure if the upgradation was completed successfully or not. My files are safe afer the restart. But how can I be sure that everything is okay. Can anyone please help me about this matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at /etc/apt/sources.list a there lines for ubuntu18?

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted

If yes, then just make command in console:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Comment: My /etc/apt/sources.list is

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse 

#Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted multiverse universe

Comment: I used sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get uprade. It worked as

Fetched 1,741 kB in 3s (523 kB/s)              
Reading package lists... Done

and 

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Is it alright ??